# C++ OpenMP: schedule tasks of very unequal size

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, sorting, openmp

I have to sort a collection of vectors with OpenMP in C++. I really think this should be a common problem; however, I never found anything about it.

Of course I could just use

```
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for(int i =0; i<narrays; ++i)
      sortSerial(array[i]);
```

and leave the scheduling to the runtime.

However, one array could take longer than all the others combined. Actually, I might well only have one array. 
Or I might, say, have twenty thousands with a hundred elements each, plus two with a million each. In that case, if I have 8 cores, I'd like to assign five thousands *sections per thread* for the first four threads, and then two *threads per section* with the last four. So that the total time is constant.

I might then use nested parallelism. But if I do this

```
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for(int i =0; i<narrays; ++i)
      sortParallel(array[i]);
```

where sortParallel spawns the correct number of threads to balance the workload, OMP will still start processing as many threads as possible; and then the nested parallelism will most probably oversubscribe. This seems bad, especially since the sortParallel routine has a lot of barriers.

The ideal solution would be to tell for how many threds every iteration will need, so that it might avoid starting new tasks if it would oversubscribe, but this doesn't seem possible.

I might have to notice that it should compile under VisualStudio 2013, so, it seems OpenMP 2.0 -and in particular, no tasks.

I am now exploring weird combinations of deep nestings of parallel region. But I'd really rather not do that. Is there some obvious solution I am missing?

My last design starts from the fact that, if the thread division is done correctly, then the big sections never take (too much) longer than total/threads. And the same will do the small sections, if we properly divide them among the remaining threads. So we don't really need to scramble to reuse the threads we used to sort the bigger vectors; since they will finish (alas, roughly) all at the same time anyway. 
Therefore, I can just divide long intervals and small intervals in different vectors, put in threads[i] a partition of the number of threads which tries to create optimal balance, and do this

```
void sort(int i,int threads){
    if(i<nbigintervals) //sort one big interval
       sortParallel(bigInterval[i],threads);  //spawns threads threads
    else                //sort all the others
       #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1) num_threads(threads)  //nested parallel section, assigning the remaining vectors in dynamic fashion.
           for(int j=0;j<nsmallintervals;++j)
              sortSerial(smallInterval[j]);
}

int main() {
//....
//assign vectors of intervals
//balance threads

omp_set_nested(true);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1) num_threads(nbigintervals +1)
   for(int i=0; i<=nbigintervals; ++i) //notice the less _or equal_, which adds one iteration (and makes their number match the number of threads requested)
      sort(i,threads[i]);
 //....
 }
```

This avoids oversubscription, since the threads spawned by each iteration are designed to sum to the available total. Is there a simpler/cleaner/faster solution?

Comment: The approach looks neat and very clever. I was about to mention that `OMP_NUM_THREADS` can take a list of value, corresponding to the number of threads to use at each depth of nested parallelism, but it turns out that this wasn't supported in OpenMP version 2.0. So this isn't an option for you. Anyway, that could have permitted you to avoid over-subscription in a simple way, but ultimately it would have been way poorer than what you proposed here.

Comment: It seems I could emulate that by passing the value to num_threads a each level, is it just a shortcut or is there more to it?

Comment: It is just a feature of OpenMP added since [version 3.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf#G6.997487). I thought about it because you said "then the nested parallelism will most probably oversubscribe" since it would prevent that. But again, your solution is better so just stick to it.